# Add existing maven libraries defined in separated xml files to intellij project

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, addition, pom.xml

I have a project contains many xml files of maven library (e.g. "com_googlecode_json_simple_json_simple_1_1_1.xml"). Now I want to import these libraries to another project in IntelliJ. Please note that none of my projects is maven project in which pom.xml file exists.

Answer (score 1):

There is an iml file named "**Project_Name.iml**" in the root directory of new project. Just open it in an editor (such as Notepad++). Also open this file of old project. You can see some lines specify dependencies:

```
<orderEntry type="library" name="com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="commons-io:commons-io:2.5" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" name="net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.27" level="project" />
```

Just copy these lines to new project's iml file. Not to forget to copy all dependencies' XML files from directory **.idea/libraries** of old project to new project's one.

Now you should see all libraries listed in the dependencies list of new project.

[image: Intellij view of dependencies]